# Dynamically Manage Edit-Rights in Keycloak

Tags: authentication, dynamic, keycloak, quarkus, rights

currently I'm building a Backend-Service in Quarkus with Keycloak as the Auth-system for a sort of Blog-Application. I somehow have to solve the following problem:

If a user creates a new blog-post, only the user has the rights to edit it afterwards. So how can I realize this? Is there a way in Keycloak to kind of dynamically add rights to a User for his blog-post? Or would you rather recommend storing the Username in the Blog-Post DB and then check if the username issuing the token is the same for as the "BlogCreatorUsername" in the DB?

Any help appreciated

Comment: IMHO the 2nd approach should be taken; I'm not aware of Keycloak dynamically updating the permissions - Keycloak is not aware of the context in which the currently authenticated user operates

Comment: I second @SergeyBeryozkin's approach. On a technical level, we could extract either the `preferred_username`, `email` or the `sub` (keycloak-internal UUID) from the JWT to identify the user. I would most probably take the `sub` claim since this claim is the one that is most likely not changed.